# Whats the regular expression for a colon separated value?

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string such as:

```
blah blah item: value blah blah
```

What would the expression be to just get value?

Comment: What do you need it for? Are you trying to parse JSON yourself?

Comment: are other `item:value` pairs included in the `blah blah` parts of your string?

Comment: Yes there are other pairs included. I have tried: item:\s*(\d+). But this gives me the item as well. I want the just the value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this `regex`

`:\s*(\w+)`

`$1` or group 1 has the required value

---

`\s*` matches 0 to many spaces

`\w+` matches 1 to many characters which can be any 1 of `[a-zA-Z\d_]`

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression would be

```
:
```

As in,

```
String value = yourString.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

for your exact String, using **`**String.split()**`**

```
String s="blah blah item: value blah blah";
System.out.println(s.split("(:\\s+)")[1].split("\\s")[0]);

Output: value
```

Comment: nice..but still uses regex..;)

Comment: split() takes regex as a parameter :P