# javascript regular expression - getting value after colon, without the colon

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have tried the https://www.regex101.com/#javascript tool, as well as a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727892/whats-the-regular-expression-for-a-colon-separated-value) and yet haven't been able to solve/understand this. Hopefully someone here can explain what I am doing wrong. I have created as detailed, step-by-step of an example as I can.

My goal is to be able to parse custom attributes, so for example:

I wrote some jquery code to pull in the attribute and the value, and then wanted to run regex against the result.

Below is the html/js, the output screenshot, and the regular expression screenshot, which says my regex query should match what I am expecting.

Expected result: 'valOne'
Result: ':valOne' <-- why am I getting a ':' character?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[customAttr]').each(function(){

          var attrValues = $(this).attr('customAttr');

          var regEx_attrVal = /[\w:]+?(?=;|$)/g;
          var regEx_preColon = /[\w]+?(?=:)/g;
          var regEx_postColon = /:(\w*)+?(?=;|\b)/g;

          var customAttrVal = attrValues.match(regEx_attrVal);
          var customAttrVal_string = customAttrVal.toString();
          console.log('customAttrVal:');
          console.log(customAttrVal);
          console.log('customAttrVal_string: '+customAttrVal_string);

          var preColon = customAttrVal_string.match(regEx_preColon);
          preColon_string =preColon.toString();
          console.log('preColon');
          console.log(preColon);
          console.log('preColon_string: '+preColon_string);

          var postColon = customAttrVal_string.match(regEx_postColon);
          postColon_string = postColon.toString();
          console.log('postColon');
          console.log(postColon);
          console.log('postColon_string: '+postColon_string);

          console.log('pre: '+preColon_string);
          console.log('post: '+postColon_string);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div customAttr="val1:valOne">
        Test custom attr
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Instead of posting images, please post link of regex101. Also post some test data, what should be considered as successful match and what not.

Comment: The problem is in the javascript code. You should get the group, not do `toString` directly. I forgot the JS code to do it though

Comment: just split on colons. `var pair="val1:valOne".split(":"); // pair[0]=val1, pair[1]=valOne`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `String#match()` with a regex with a global modifier, all the capture groups (those strings in the regex101.com right-hand bottom 'MATCH INFORMATION' pane are the values *captured* into Groups with ID 1 and higher) defined in the pattern are lost, and you only get an array of matched values.

You need to remove `/g` from your regexps and fix them as follows:

```
var regEx_attrVal = /[\w:]+(?=;|$)/;
var regEx_preColon = /\w+(?=:)/;
var regEx_postColon = /:(\w+)(?=;|\b)/;
```

Then, when getting the `regEx_postColon` captured value, use

```
var postColon = customAttrVal_string.match(regEx_postColon);
var postColon_string = postColon !== null ? postColon[1] : "";
```

First, check if there is a `postColon` regex match, then access the *captured value* with `postColon[1]`.

See the whole updated code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[customAttr]').each(function() {

    var attrValues = $(this).attr('customAttr');

    var regEx_attrVal = /[\w:]+(?=;|$)/;
    var regEx_preColon = /\w+(?=:)/;
    var regEx_postColon = /:(\w+)(?=;|\b)/;

    var customAttrVal = attrValues.match(regEx_attrVal);
    var customAttrVal_string = customAttrVal.toString();
    console.log('customAttrVal:');
    console.log(customAttrVal);
    console.log('customAttrVal_string: ' + customAttrVal_string);

    var preColon = customAttrVal_string.match(regEx_preColon);
    preColon_string = preColon.toString();
    console.log('preColon');
    console.log(preColon);
    console.log('preColon_string: ' + preColon_string);

    var postColon = customAttrVal_string.match(regEx_postColon);
    var postColon_string = postColon !== null ? postColon[1] : "";
    console.log('postColon');
    console.log(postColon);
    console.log('postColon_string: ' + postColon_string);

    console.log('pre: ' + preColon_string);
    console.log('post: ' + postColon_string);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div customAttr="val1:valOne">
  Test custom attr
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor it works great and thanks for breaking it down. In case you/others feel like answering a follow up question, is there a more efficient way to achieve my goal of being able to tag code with custom tags and parsing them? For example, let's say I want to automatically generate documentation on code like this: <div documentation="message:firstVisit">hello world</div>. I am looking to get all DOM elements marked by 'documentation' and then parse their tags to generate the docs. I currently am going for the above approach. Any recommendations for a better way?

Comment: It looks like you need to use JQuery like `$('[documentation]').each(function() {
    // Process the tag
});`. And then just use the DOM properties to get what you need. I am afraid I cannot help more since what you ask is too broad. Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/excLn0hs/).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't trudged through all the code, but something you need to understand about regexes is the difference between `$0` and `$1`.

`$0` is highlighted in blue. That is the entire part the regex matched.

You want `$1`. That's where the matches captured by the parenthesis are.

Read more about capture groups [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/6083675).

```
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  // This accesses $1
```

Comment: You explained how regex101 works, not the issues with the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's important to know how to use the tools. But I'm also  addressing the JS side of things.

Comment: Yes, you have just added a bit, but there are actually more issues.

Answer (score 1):

use data attributes. you can store json strings in them and access them like objects.

**HTML**

`<div id='div' data-custom='{"val1":"valOne","a":"b"}'></div>`

**jQ**

`$("#div").data("custom").val1; //valOne`

`$("#div").data("custom").a; //b`

Comment: Thanks for showing me that possible solution, as I didn't know you could store json strings in data attributes. If you didn't know what any of the keys would be, how could you access them? For example, if you have data-custom peppered throughout your code, each one with different values, how would you iterate through them? The following is not written correctly, but how could I do something like: $('body').data('custom').each(function(index, value) {
          console.log(index, value)
        });

Comment: that looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the `regex pattern` that you're looking for:

`(?!(.*?):).*`

**Explanation**

- `(.*?:)` Select all type of values and any number of times and a match that contains (:) simbol
- `(?!  :)` select inverse values of the first pattern, its kinda negation
- `(  ).*` Select all type of values after the evaluations

Also you can do the same with `Jquery substring` which for me the most simple way to do it, just like this:

[How to substring in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126762/how-to-substring-in-jquery)